# Django Rest Framework - self.request.user in model method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

`User` is the django User model from `django.contrib.auth.models`

```
# drink/models.py
class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    bartender = models.ForeignKey('bartender.Bartender')

# bartender/models.py
class Bartender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

# property/models.py
class Rating(models.Model):
    bartender = models.ForeignKey('bartender.Bartender')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I use django rest framework and would like a serializer Field as such:

```
# bartender/serializers.py
class BartenderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = serializers.IntegerField(source='get_rating', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bartender
        fields = []
```

My Viewset is

```
class BartenderViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bartender.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BartenderSerializer
```

how do I add a model method to my `Bartender` model, such that it returns the `Rating` object for whatever `User` is making the call.

I tried this modification to my `Bartender` class:

```
# bartender/models.py
class Bartender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_rating(self):
        return Rating.objects.get(bartender=self.id, owner=self.request.user)
```

However `self` has no request. Therefore, I would like to know how to implement this so it is callable via drf viewsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do this without modifying your model. Just evaluate data on serializer level with [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class BartenderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bartender
        fields = []

    def get_rating(self, obj):
        return Rating.objects.get(bartender=obj.id, owner=self.context.get('request').user).values('rating')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. However, I had to add `.values('rating')` as I received the error `Object Rating is not JSON serializable` I edited your answer correspondingly.